# Illustrator - Removing the blank space below a letter

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, png

### Objective

I am trying to create a logo in png format with the size of 512x512. The shape is round, so i need the edges of the background to be transparent.

### Problem

The letter has some weird space underneath that exceeds the container and that is preventing me from getting an even square shape around the circle.

[image]

### Question

What steps need to be taken to remove that blank space around the text or how can i constrain the text not to exceed the circle?

Keep in mind that I am not a designer so may not understand some of the vocabulary related to typography or Illustrator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the text and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Mac or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Win to convert the text to outline.

Answer (score 5):

^ I also recommend using the 'create outlines' shortcut as Danielillo mentioned above, but wanted to add that you can find the tool in the menu bar under Type>Create Outlines.

It is probably important to note that in 'creating outlines,' the letter 'U' will be reformatted into a vector object (outlined paths), so you will no longer be able to alter/edit it in the character settings panel.

Answer (score 2):

No need to outline the **U**. Create a square artboard or a slice in the size you need, center your design in that and then `Save for Web` that artboard or slice. You can switch on transparency in the PNG export dialogue.

Comment: Technically yes, but I'd argue with that: you should always outline fonts in logos, because these will eventually get passed around between different providers, many times not including the font files. I have seen this so many times that i think unconverted logos just show a complete lack of experience and wasting the client`s time. A client generally does not know what happens when his uncorverted logo is sent to print without the font files.

Comment: This might not be a logo and the question was not about packaging assets to pass them on, but how to export a square PNG with transparency.

Comment: Question does include the word "logo", hence my comment.

Answer (score 2):

For a non-destructive solution, you could use a [Clipping Mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html).

Duplicate the circle, place it on top of the text, select both the duplicated circle and the text and use <kbd>Object → Clipping Mask → Make</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot of Illustrator]

A non-destructive workflow will allow you to edit the text later if needed.

Comment: Thanks, in many cases i think this would be a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create outlines as the others suggested, but also keep a copy of the U or the entire artwork before converting to outlines. It may be useful for the future to keep an editable version.